# How do you specify the SQLite database file in FireDAC's TFDPhysSQLiteDriverLink component?

Tags: database, sqlite, delphi, firedac, delphi-10-seattle

I'm trying to modify [one of the FireDAC sample projects](http://sourceforge.net/p/radstudiodemos/code/HEAD/tree/branches/RADStudio_Seattle/Object%20Pascal/Database/FireDAC/Samples/DBMS%20Specific/SQLite/OnUpdate) in order to use an existing SQLite file as the database source. The sample works fine unmodified and connects to its database. However, I can't figure out where the database it connects to is specified, in order to change it.

[According to the documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Connect_to_SQLite_database_(FireDAC)#Connection_Definition_Parameters), there should be a `Database` property on the `TFDPhysSQLiteDriverLink` component.  There isn't: it doesn't exist. I even converted the form to text and looked through all components' customized properties, and there's no path defined anywhere. Nor is there in code - the sample is very small and there's no path defined at all.

The other option on the documentation is to include the `FireDAC.Phys.SQLite` unit, although that doesn't explain how to set the database, since as far as I can tell that unit just includes the component. And when I search for Database properties (see attached image) none of them in any class in that unit seem to be quite what I'm after.  The closest is a string that's for a backup component - I doubt that's what I need.  There is a `SQLiteDatabase` property in the `TFDPhysSQLiteConnection` class but that's read-only.

> [image: List of all Database properties defined in the FireDAC.Phys.SQLite unit]
>
> *List of all Database properties defined in the FireDAC.Phys.SQLite unit*

I also tried [creating a temporary connection definition at runtime](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Defining_Connection_(FireDAC)#Creating_a_Temporary_Connection_Definition), by double-clicking the `TFDConnection` component. That only gives an exception:

> [image: Exception double-clicking the TFDConnection component]
>
> *Exception double-clicking the TFDConnection component*

The only solution to this I found is in the XE5 documentation, where it says [to set the `$(PUBLICDOCUMENTSDIR)` environment variable](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Release_Notes_for_XE5_Update_1#Set_the_Registry_Value_for_.24.28PUBLICDOCUMENTSDIR.29_in_order_to_use_a_FireDAC_TFDConnection). I already had to do that to get the demo to run (previously, it threw the same exception on the line `FDConnection1.Connected := True;`; it doesn't now, the demo runs perfectly at runtime.) That change obviously hasn't affected the designer, and I don't even know if I'm looking in the right place, since after all the documentation talks about setting the `Database` property.

So I'm stumped. Where does it set the database?  It's not in the DFM or any streamed properties; it's not in the property defined by the documentation (`TFDPhysSQLiteDriverLink.Database` doesn't exist, nor does anything that looks like it); it's not in the `TFDConnection` designtime editor (even though it throws an exception, a file specified as a property here would appear in the streamed DFM, I'd think); it's not in code; ...where else can it be?

(I have never used FireDAC before so am a complete noob, btw. I'm self-teaching via the documentation and samples.)

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually need a TFDPhysSQLiteDriverLink for a minimalist FireDAC project, and using one rather confuses the issue if you're trying to make a connection to a database for the first time.

Try this:

- Make a note of the name including path of a Sqlite db.
- Start a new VCL project and drop a TFDconnection, TFDQuery, TDataSource & TDBGrid onto its form and connection them up.  Set the TDFQuery's Sql to select * from some table you know exists in the db.
- Right-click the TFDConnection and select `Connection editor` from the pop-up.
- Set the `DriverID` to `SQLite` and insert your db name into the `Database` `Value` box.
- Open the FDQuery.

If you compile and run the project, you'll get an exception telling you a class factory for a TFDGUIxWaitCursor is missing (this is the sort of thing I love about FireDAC), but that's easily fixed by dropping one onto your form.  Notice that you don't have to connect it using the `Object Inspector` to any of the other FD components.

After that, you can add a `TFDPhysSQLiteDriverLink` and set its `DriverID` to the same as for the `TFDConnection`.

Comment: Thanks Martyn. I think the Connection Editor is what threw the exception (see above) but I'll try that again. Your steps are clear and explain things well, thankyou!

Comment: The way I did it was just to include the full path of the .Sqlite file in the Database Value box in the Connection editor - that's all I had to do.  I'm using XE8 btw.

Comment: Thanks - I deleted my comment since I figured it out (I misread what you wrote and was looking at the wrong text box, not the parameters below) but you replied anyway ;)

Answer (score 1):

I ussualy roll my own class and handle the `OnBeforeConnect` event

Something like this

```
procedure TSQLiteConnection.SQLiteConnectionBeforeConnect(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if not(TFile.Exists(DatabaseFilePath)) then
    Params.Values['OpenMode'] := 'CreateUTF16'
  else
    Params.Values['OpenMode'] := 'ReadWrite';

  Params.Values['Database'] := DatabaseFilePath;
  DriverName := 'SQLite';
end;
```

The `DatabaseFilePath` is just a string field of the class, so basically you can put any file path there

TSQLiteConnection is, of course, a TFDConnection descendant

Comment: Ah, so there's no Database property, but a string parameter?

Comment: Yep, because some DBMS are not file-based (like say, SQLite, Firebird) but think on MS SQL Server; you don't specify a file on the disk, you actually set an alias of the DB in the connection string

Comment: Either way it's still a connection string, though, isn't it, whether that's a filename or something else? And the documentation did very clearly say there was a Database property...

Comment: The documentation is "correct", but not very accurate :)

Those that you link are the parameters of the TFDConnection. And, specifically, the ones in the chart are those that are supported by SQLite.. -

Check [this](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Common_Connection_Parameters_(FireDAC))

Comment: Maybe what you need is something like [this](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Defining_Connection_(FireDAC)#At_Run-Time)